# does it reduce the resources usage on a VPS server if we portion the sites to 2 seperate IP

Tags: ip, vps, resource-management

We are using a VPS server in our company and we're moving our clients' sites to our new server. The resources usage looks fine now, but I assume it will get higher when we move more sites into the server. We have 2 static IP addresses and we mostly use only one of them.

I was wondering if we migrate more sites to the 2nd IP address, would it help reduce resource usage?
What are the ways to reduce the resource usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, logical changes like that will have no impact on physical resource usage.

You can reduce resource usage in all the typical ways:

- Efficient code/queries
- Caching
- Separate static and dynamic content